# Firebase recycler view does not show images on recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I am new to working firebase. I managed to upload text and images, however, i cannot retrieve images to be displayed into my recycler views, only text is retrieved. *I am using Picasso dependency*. I have included my MainActivity.java class which is responsible for displaying recycler view items retrieved from the firebase in the question, my adapter. java class and model class. I believe that I might have made the mistake of not storing an **image URI** when I was uploading it into the firebase storage hence the adapter cannot retrieve the image location. I think this might be the case because I came across similar situations when I was researching the problem. Please assist

**Below is the code for my model java class**

```
public class Model {

    // string variable for
    // storing employee name.
    private String journeyName;

    // string variable for storing
    // employee contact number
    private String journeyDescription;

    // string variable for storing
    // employee address.
    private String journeyLocation;

    //lets experiment with an id
    private String journeyId;

    //an url for an image
    private String imageURL;

    // an empty constructor is
    // required when using
    // Firebase Realtime Database.


    public Model() {

    }

    protected Model(Parcel in){
        journeyName = in.readString();
        journeyDescription = in.readString();
        journeyLocation = in.readString();
        journeyId = in.readString();
        imageURL = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Model> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Model>(){
        @Override
        public Model createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Model(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Model[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Model[size];
        }
    };



    // created getter and setter methods
    // for all our variables.
    public String getJourneyName() {
        return journeyName;
    }

    public void setJourneyName(String journeyName) {
        this.journeyName = journeyName;
    }

    public String getJourneyDescription() {
        return journeyDescription;
    }

    public void setJourneyDescription(String journeyDescription) {
        this.journeyDescription = journeyDescription;
    }

    public String getJourneyLocation() {
        return journeyLocation;
    }

    public void setJourneyLocation(String journeyLocation) {
        this.journeyLocation = journeyLocation;
    }

    public String getJourneyId() {
        return journeyId;
    }

    public void setJourneyId(String journeyId) {
        this.journeyId = journeyId;
    }

    public String getImageURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
    }

    public Model(String journeyName, String journeyDescription, String journeyLocation, String journeyId, String url) {

        this.journeyName = journeyName;
        this.journeyDescription = journeyDescription;
        this.journeyLocation = journeyLocation;
        this.journeyId = journeyId;
        this.imageURL = url;
    }


    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }


    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(journeyName);
        dest.writeString(journeyDescription);
        dest.writeString(journeyLocation);
        dest.writeString(journeyId);
        dest.writeString(imageURL);
    }
}
```

**My adapter code below**

```
public class JourneyRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<JourneyRVAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    //creating variables for our list, context interface and position
    private ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;
    private Context context;
    private JourneyClickInterface journeyClickInterface;
    int lastPos = -1;

    //creating a constructor
    public JourneyRVAdapter(ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList, Context context, JourneyClickInterface journeyClickInterface) {
        this.modelArrayList = modelArrayList;
        this.context = context;
        this.journeyClickInterface = journeyClickInterface;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public JourneyRVAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //inflating our layout file below on line
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //setting data to our recycler view item on below line.
        Model model = modelArrayList.get(position);
        holder.titleTV.setText(model.getJourneyName());
        holder.DescTV.setText(model.getJourneyDescription());
        holder.LocationTV.setText(model.getJourneyLocation());

        Picasso.get().load(model.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .fit()
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.imageIV);

        // adding animation to recycler view item on below line.
        setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
        holder.rowLY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                journeyClickInterface.onJourneyClick(position);
            }
        });

    }

    private void setAnimation(View itemView, int position) {
        ///animations implement own logic!!!
        if (position > lastPos) {
            // on below line we are setting animation.
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            itemView.setAnimation(animation);
            lastPos = position;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
      return modelArrayList.size();
       // return (modelArrayList == null) ? 0 : modelArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //creating variable for our imageview and text views below
        private ImageView imageIV;
        private TextView titleTV, DescTV, LocationTV;
        private LinearLayout rowLY;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            //initializing all our variables on below line
            imageIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rImageView);
            titleTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rTitleView);
            DescTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rDescriptionTv);
            LocationTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rLocationTv);
            rowLY = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardRow);


        }
    }

    // creating an interface for on click
    public interface JourneyClickInterface {
        void onJourneyClick(int position);
    }
}
```

Code for the Main Activity This is where I will be displaying my recycler view items

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FloatingActionButton FloatingActionButton;

    // creating variables for fab, firebase database,
    // progress bar, list, adapter,firebase auth,
    // recycler view and relative layout.
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    StorageReference storageReference;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    private RecyclerView journeyRV;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    //private ProgressBar loadingPB;

    private ArrayList<Model> modelArrayList;

    private JourneyRVAdapter journeyRVAdapter;

    private RelativeLayout homeRL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        //initialize
        journeyRV = findViewById(R.id.idRVJourneys);
        //homeRL = findViewById(R.id.)
        //loadingPB
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        modelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        //on below line we are getting database reference.
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Journeys");

        //reference for our storage db
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images1");

        // on below line adding a click listener for our floating action button.
        FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class));
            }
        });
        // on below line initializing our adapter class.
        journeyRVAdapter = new JourneyRVAdapter(modelArrayList, this, this::onJourneyClick);
        //setting layout manager to recycler view on below line
        journeyRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        // setting adapter to recycler view on below line.
        journeyRV.setAdapter(journeyRVAdapter);
        //on below line calling a method to fetch courses from database
        getJourneys();

    }

    private void getJourneys() {
        //on below line we are clearing our list
        modelArrayList.clear();
        //on below line we are calli g add child event listener methods to read the data
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                //hide progress bar

                //then add snap shot to our array list on below line
                modelArrayList.add(snapshot.getValue(Model.class));
                //notify our adapter that data has changed
                journeyRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                //this method is called when new child is added
                // we are notifying our adapter and making progress bar
                // visibility as gone.
                //loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                journeyRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // notifying our adapter when child is removed.
                journeyRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                // notifying our adapter when child is moved.
                //loadingPB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                journeyRVAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Code for adding new entries / records to my firebase realtime database and storage

```
public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        //initializing our edt and btn
        journeyNameEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtJourneyName);
        journeyDescriptionEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtJourneyDescription);
        journeyLocationEdt = findViewById(R.id.idEdtJourneyLocation);

        // for myn image view
        imgView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        //get instance of our firebase database
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        //reference for our storage db
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images1");

        //get reference of our database
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Journeys");

        //initializing our object
        //class variable
        model = new Model();

        sendDatabtn = findViewById(R.id.idBtnSendData);

        btnbrowse = findViewById(R.id.btnbrowse);

        //browse imagery
        btnbrowse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), Image_Request_Code);
            }
        });

        //adding an onClick listener for sending data
        sendDatabtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if(FilePathUri != null){
                String journey = journeyNameEdt.getText().toString();
                String description = journeyDescriptionEdt.getText().toString();
                String location = journeyLocationEdt.getText().toString();
                String url = FilePathUri.getPath();
                journeyId = journey;

                //below line is for checking weather the edittext files are empty or not
                Model model = new Model(journeyId, journey, description, location,url);


                addDataFirebase(journey, description, location);

                UploadImage();}
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please make selection ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Image_Request_Code && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){

            FilePathUri = data.getData();

            try{
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), FilePathUri);
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    public String GetFileExtension (Uri uri){

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(contentResolver.getType(uri));
    }

    public void UploadImage(){

        if (FilePathUri != null) {
            StorageReference storageReference1 = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+ "."+ GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));
            storageReference1.putFile(FilePathUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Please Select Image or Add Image Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void addDataFirebase (String journey, String description, String location){
        // these below lines are used to set data in our object class
        model.setJourneyName(journey);
        model.setJourneyDescription(description);
        model.setJourneyLocation(location);

        //we are to use an add value event listener method
        //this is called with database reference
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                //inside here we are setting our object class to our database reference
                //database reference will send data to firebase

                databaseReference.child(journeyId).setValue(model);

                //databaseReference.setValue(model);

                //if successful show toast
                Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "data added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                //if failed show toast
                Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Failed to add data"+ error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**My real-time database nodes displayed below**

[image: Realtime Database image]

Comment: By the way, there isn't an error displayed on the Logcat pane

Comment: "*I believe that I might have made the mistake of not storing an image URI when I was uploading it into the firebase storage*" - are you saying you don't know if you've stored an image URL or not?  That's not something we can help you with.  You will have to check that on your own and do some debugging to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: did you check the database if the value exists

Comment: The URL value does not exist on the real-time database but the code manages to upload images to the firebase storage using the URL

Answer (score 1):

You can add more field into your firebase to save imageUrl, if you want get imageUrl you can add code this below on method UploadImage.

```
public void UploadImage(){

    if (FilePathUri != null) {
        StorageReference storageReference1 = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+ "."+ GetFileExtension(FilePathUri));
        storageReference1.putFile(FilePathUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                storageReference1.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> { url = uri.toString(); }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this, "Please Select Image or Add Image Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

so the value of imageUrl is Url from Firestorage and the Url that Picasso load is Url from Firestorage.

Answer (score 0):

I will use this method to upload photos
It is highly secured and also works in the background so that the user cannot intentionally stop the image loading and errors occur :
// You can also upload multiple photos, not just one

```
public class UploadImageService extends IntentService {
    public UploadImageService () {
        super("UploadImageService ");
    }

    protected FirebaseFirestore db; // this Code if youe using Firestore only
    protected DocumentReference user_doc ; // this Code if youe using Firestore only
    // if Firebase RealTime Just Remove `db` An `usee_doc`
    protected ArrayList<String> Urix = new ArrayList<>();
    protected FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    protected StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference().child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()));
    

    protected String Post_Key;

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

        Urix = workIntent.getExtras().getStringArrayList("Uri");
        Post_Key = workIntent.getExtras().getString("Post_Key");
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        for (int i = 0; i < Urix.size(); i++)
        {
            SendThis(i);
        }



    }


    public void SendThis (int Currrents)
    {

        final String Current = Urix.get(Currrents);
        File file = new File(Urix.get(Currrents));

        int fin = getRandomNumber(900) * getRandomNumber(900) + getRandomNumber(10000) ;

        storageRef.child(getRandomNumber(10000) + file.getName() + fin  ).putFile(Uri.parse(Urix.get(Currrents)))
                .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                    
                    Update(uri.toString());
                }))
                .addOnFailureListener(e -> {

                });

    }


    private void Update(String url)
    {
        //Post Key to get child path
        // url is your image URL 
        // Now Just get your child path and add the image url


    }

    private int getRandomNumber(int max) {
        return (new Random()).nextInt((max - 1) + 1) + 1;
    }
```

}

//In Your Action 'UploadImageActivity or Main Activity' add this code to Start the Task :

```
public void SendThis (String XS)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(CreateUploadTitle.this ,UploadImageService.class);
    
    intent.putExtra("Uri" , YourCurrentImagePath);
    intent.putExtra("Post_Key" , yourPostKeyAfterUploadData);
    startService(intent);
}
```

// And in your mainfests :

```
 <service android:name=".PostSystem.Server.UploadVideoService"
            android:exported="false" />
```

// Now to get Your Image just Get the name in your Database
// And if you have Currect `Firebase ruls`